# NULL returned by my sql request

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables :

[image]

I would like to display city and postal code, but for the postal code, I obtain NULL.

This is my sql request :

```
SELECT pays_cp_ville.*, villes.libelle, codes_postaux.code_postal FROM pays_cp_ville
        LEFT JOIN codes_postaux
            ON pays_cp_ville.ville_id = codes_postaux.id
        LEFT JOIN villes
            ON pays_cp_ville.ville_id = villes.id
        WHERE pays_cp_ville.code_postal_id = 11 AND pays_cp_ville.ville_id = 43672
```

this is the result :

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is the issue here? It seems like a data issue - where there is no database entry matching this criteria `pays_cp_ville.ville_id = codes_postaux.id`

Comment: In fact, I did a mistake in my sql statement.  ON pays_cp_ville.code_postal_id = codes_postaux.id and not pays_cp_ville.ville_id = codes_postaux.id Thank you for your help and best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake in my sql request :

Error : pays_cp_ville.ville_id = codes_postaux.id

Correction : pays_cp_ville.code_postal_id = codes_postaux.id

Comment: You should delete your question.